# Check if session is null is returning error

Tags: c#, session

I'm using jQuery to get a few values and them i send to an Webservice. 
On that WebService i'm checking if a session is null but i'm receiving Null Reference to that session and it gets error (i see it on javascript console, on debugging i just see the error on output "A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PromotorDeSaude.DLL".

I'm checking if session is null like this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["encomenda"] != null)
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access Session in a web service method, add the attribute

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

to the method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much Andreas. In fact i don't know almost anything about WebMethods, i've started used them 2 days ago because JSON.
I guess it's better to read a little more about WebMethods.

Thanks again ;)

Comment: You are welcome, I have done exactly the same mistake myself :-). If my answer fix your problem, please mark as answer.

Comment: I know, i'm waiting for the 3 minutes to accepet it (stackoverlow rule i guess)

Answer (score 1):

That suggests that `HttpContext.Current` or `HttpContext.Current.Session` may be null - which would happen if you're running on a different thread, for example.

I suggest you log every bit of the expression to find out which bit is null, and work from there.

Comment: I've just tried to create a new session trough "HttpContext.Current.Session["encomenda"]="a";" but i get null reference too.
Is this the proper way to create an session, or it should be created in global.asax when the app begins for example?

Comment: @Guilherme, did you try Jon's suggestion?  He was indicating that *`HttpContext.Current`* itself might be null.  Did you check for that?  Also, you're not "creating a session" with that line.  You're assigning the value `"a"` to the session under the name "encomenda".

Comment: It was my mistake, because i wasn't enabling sessions in WebMethod.